# what is wrong with this mathematical assumption

Tags: math, geometry

I have 2 3D points A and B I now assume the parametric equation like:

```
x = Ax + (Bx*t)
y = Ay + (By*t)
z = Az + (Bz*t)
```

So this can be refined to:

```
x = Ax + (Bx * ((y - Ay)/By));
```

is correct.
Given this I want to know what the coordinates of a point(on A-B) at height 0 are.

so I now do this:

```
float y = 0;
float t = ((y - Ay) / By)
float x = Ax + (Bx * t);
float z = Az + (Bz * t);
```

Is there anything mathematically wrong with this?
(my code is not doing what should be happening with this)

Thanks!

PS: The relevance of this question to programming:
In a game engine when projecting points(in this case corners of my view frustum) onto a plane such as the xz-plane with y = 0 this mathematical problem coincides with my game-programming

Comment: This looks like more of a [math.se] question than a programming question.

Comment: What are x and t in `x = Ax + (Bx*t)`?

Comment: @Dukeling thats why i tagged this question as math :)

Comment: Any question on [so] should be primarily a programming question. The [tag:math] tag is for primarily programming questions involving some maths, not primarily maths involving some programming. The field of programming is so broad that you can basically ask a question about anything because you're writing a program about it, but we can't have StackOverflow include all of this. There are sites that focus specifically on other topics where such questions would be more appropriate, such as [math.se].

Comment: If he'd written A.x and B.y instead of Ax and By, would that have made this into a programming related question?

Answer (score 2):

I would write them this way:

```
x = A*(1-t) + B*t
```

So `x(0) = A` and `x(1) = B`.  Writing it this way assumes `0 <= t <= +1`.

Another way to think about it is to assume `-1 <= t <= +1`.    If you go that way the shape functions look like this:

```
x = A*(1-t)/2.0 + B*(1+t)/2.0
```

Once again `x(-1) = A` and `x(+1) = B`.

And it's easy to generalize to higher-order functions:

```
x(t) = A*t(t-1)/2 + C*(1-t^2) + B*t(t+1)/2
```

So `x(0) = A`, `x(0.5) = C`, `x(1) = B`.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is a bit cryptic though :). I think you mean Ax and Bx were you used A and B(tell me if I`m wrong :) ) And this would mean i would change my x = To x= Ax - Ax*t + Bx*t(specificly this is the same answer as above only harder to understand, for me that is).

Comment: No, I deliberately wrote it the way I did.  A and B and the values of x at either end of the line; t is the parameterization.  What I wrote is correct; yours is confusing.

Comment: I didnt mean to insult or say that the answer was wrong :). I merely wanted to state that there was a jump in reasoning from the question I posed to the answer you gave. Which seeing I allready was unsure about the subject of the question mqde it even more difficult to follow :). But I do Indeed believe the answer to be correct

Comment: +1 This IS the nicest way, IMHO, to write it. It makes it perfectly clear that when t=0 or t=1 you get the original points back. And when t=1/2, it is again clear that you get the midpoint. Once you get used to seeing this form, you will indeed prefer it.

Answer (score 1):

I think your parametrization is wrong:

```
x = Ax + (Bx*t)
...
```

But it should be:

```
x = Ax + ((Bx-Ax)*t)
...
```

Comment: i will test this later, but indeed it looks to be my mistake, thanks :)